# Server that (can) proves what code it is running

Tags: internet, hosted

I'm looking to host some (continuously running forever-or-for-a-period-of-time) code on a server. The code might be open-source.

While I decide what code will be running by that server, anyone else with an internet connection must be able to verify whether the code that is running is actually what it is claimed to be.

Is there a server (near bay area) or webhost that provides such hosting?

---

Bonus points: if I do not have to install anything (like how free PHP web hosts provide web interfaces).

Bonus points: free if possible, free trial otherwise, otherwise trialstart of below USD 99c/week.

Comment: What would you consider acceptable proof? Statement from the hosting company? Some kind of (hosting-company supplied) monitoring system that returns hashes of what's running?

Comment: @MichaelKohne, hashes (or the code itself) would be a straightforward solution. Eg, if a user goes to `proofhost.com/admin-foo/hello.php` and it says hello world, then he can go to `proofhost.com/admin-foo/hello.php.source` to see a hash of the code. Of course all the code must be taken into account, including all the pre-run scripts and whatever if they do run. and it must indicate that that script has been so (running) for the past x hours/days.

Comment: But then how do you know any of the returned hashes are real? I'm probably not understanding the use case, but the software providing the hashes is also running on the server in question. If you trust the server to not lie to you, why do hashes and not simple version #s or something to tell you which software is running? If you DON'T trust the server, then, well, why do you trust it to give you accurate hashes?

Comment: @MichaelKohne, Yep "*simple version #s*" works too.

Comment: "anyone else with an internet connection" **is a security risk** How about ssh with a non-privileged user.  Top would show what is running.  There are dozens of ways to hash files like sha2.  You could allow said ssh user to run a script to run any kind of hashing you want.  Is this the kind of thing you want?

Comment: @cybernard, hardly riskier than any public website. Eg go [jsfiddle.net/w5c6rb09.src](https://jsfiddle.net/w5c6rb09.src) to see the proof that my server side code has been running unmodified since 06-06 1am. What **security risk?** *¶* ( I'll be glad to give jsfiddle my money but they can't do this. )